# Custom tab style (xml) not working in Android tabs (Appcelerator)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I want to change the default background color of the Android tabs. I'm creating the app with the Appcelerator framework. But changing tab styles still requires me to create xml files. So native Android developers could proabably help me too.

Anyway, i created the following xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_selector" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

In there i try to specify a `background`, reffering to `tab_selector.xml` in the `drawable` folder.

I know that part of the xml works, because it also places my tabs at the bottom.

Then in `tab_selector.xml` i have:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape> 
            <gradient 
                android:endColor="#ffffff" 
                android:startColor="#AAAAAA" 
                android:angle="270" /> 
            <stroke 
                android:width="1px" 
                android:color="#000000" /> 
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:state_selected="false" 
        android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape> 
            <gradient 
                android:endColor="#ffffff" 
                android:startColor="#AAAAAA" 
                android:angle="270" /> 
            <stroke 
                android:width="1px" 
                android:color="#000000" /> 
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- and the other states. They are the same as the ones above -->
    ...
    ...
    ...

</selector>
```

But when i run my app, i still have to old original tab styles. Any idea why my tab styles aren't applied??

Answer (score 0):

Hey you may be try [this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/135271/how-i-tabbar-position-set-in-bottom-in-android)
I think this is very useful to you,
Cheers...!